# Linq Query with Count aggregate, Group By, and Having statements

Tags: sql, oracle, linq

I can do simple linq queries and I understand the "Having" clause in SQl would be put into the where clause in linq, but because this has a join and Group by with an aggregate "Count", I can't seem to find anything on this with a simple google search.  I simply need this SQL query in Linq syntax.  I'm on Dot Net version 4.5, if that helps.

I suppose I'd prefer query syntax, but wouldn't mind learning about the method syntax.

```
SELECT t1.t1_Id, t1.ImageCount, COUNT(t2.t1_Id_ForeignKey) AS RecordsInB
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.t1_Id_ForeignKey = t1.t1_Id
GROUP BY t1.t1_Id, t1.ImageCount
HAVING t1.imageCount = COUNT(t2.t1_Id_ForeignKey)
```

Here's my attempt, but I seem to have gotten it backward or something...
It should return records in t1 where the ImageCount column is 0 and there are no records in t2 (equals 0 also).  The below attempt appears to be giving me only distinct values from t2...

```
from t1 in _db.t1
join t2 in _db.ImageRecords on a.t1_Id equals b.t1_Id_ForeignKey
group t1 by new { t1.t1_Id, t1.ImageCount } into grp
where grp.Key.ImageCount == grp.Count()
select grp.Key.t1_Id
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated

Comment: did you try [linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/)?

Comment: whats the converted version? add it to the question

Comment: I've never used linqpad.  I tried downloading and installing it, but couldn't get it to work quite right.  Something about the connection not being able to be established.

Comment: Do you mean, like the Dot Net version?  That's 4.5  Is that helpful?

Comment: Your linq query, that you added in comment, seems incorrect; you have a where clause after group by. where should be before group clause

Comment: The where clause doesn't have to be there and can't in this case because the where clause includes criteria inside the group.  I think the query I posted almost works, just realized I didn't use the aliases, though.  But it might be kinda backwards because it's pulling distinct values from t2, not all of t1.  If the value in t1 for ImageCount is 0, then it should return that record if there's no records in t2 (0 records also).  I hope that makes sense.